# Symfony2 - How to schedule image resize with EventListener

Tags: php, symfony

I build an Application with the latest Symfony2-Version. I need to do a resize process of an image after the user uploads it - this happens in `TestController::uploadAction()`.

Now I got the information that a EventListener would be the best way to do it because on `kernel.terminate` I can do it after user got response.

Following Questions:

- How do I get the Data of the Uploaded Image from Controller to the EventListener?
- How do I get the Listener to only run / interact if the TestController - uploadAction was running and the Form got Data?

Thx

Comment: "the best way to do it because on Kernel.terminate i can do it after user got response" --- it's not. Whoever told it to you is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, k - thanks - was in the Symfony IRC Channel ... Where to do it - what do you mean?

Comment: it depends on the task. In one case you would use some queue manager and resize it by a worker that listens to the queue.

Comment: User Uploads an Image - every uploaded Image needs to get resized to have an thumbnail of it. Would you use the queue manager here? If yes - is there an documentation how to do that?

Comment: google for rabbitmq. And, yep, I would use it

Comment: OK, thx - is there an alternative if i don't want to use rabbitmq now? Where to build the tumbnail ...

Comment: in the controller (that accepts a file upload) itself?

Comment: Ok this would be the best practice without rabbitmq? or doing in Entity?

Comment: I hardly doubt there is a "best practice" for this. The solution either fits your technical requirements or not. What prevents you from doing it synchronously from the controller? (by that I don't mean you need to put the whole code there but have some service instead)

Answer (score 1):

Well first you have to dispatch the event:

```
$this->container->get('event_listener')->dispatch('acme_image_upload', new MyUploadEvent($imageData, $correlation));
```

If you have any listeners on `acme_image_upload` then the associated method will be called with the event as an argument.

You can dispatch the event from a controller with access to the `Container` or `EventDispatcher`.

A good example of a bundle that handles uploads for multiple contexts is this:
https://packagist.org/packages/oneup/uploader-bundle

It uses events to handle different contexts, as well as supporting some of the most popular client side 'chunk' uploaders.